# Split comma separated values in a particular comma postion using SQL or SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have a field in SSRS that is concatenated values like

```
1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345
```

I need to break/split after 8th comma or in a particular position in next row like:

```
1234,1456,3456,
7890,3457,3245,
4345
```

Here values are dynamic but, we have to split/break at every 8th or particular comma

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why are you passing delimited values at all?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: How you are getting value like 1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345 in first place ? May be answer lies there.

Answer (score 2):

In your example text, all the values have four characters.  If that is the case, a simple recursive CTE does what you want:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), NULL) as val, convert(varchar(max), field) as rest, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select left(rest, 15) as val, stuff(rest, 1, 15, '') as rest, lev+1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select val
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d56fe848971e0f761a61e7839715813) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Dear sir, What happens if the length of each item is different with `4` ? Because according to OP said that `Here values are dynamic but, we have to split/break at 3rd comma`

Comment: I was wondering whether we can use `CHARINDEX` to find the index exactly then `LEFT` to substring instead of hard code `15`?

Comment: @Anonymous . . . This answer responds to the data you have in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've grabbed a copy of [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) (as `STRING_SPLIT` has no concept of ordinal positions) you can split the string and then "re-aggregate" it.

Using SQL Server 2017+:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = '1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345';

WITH Split AS(
    SELECT DS.Item,
           DS.ItemNumber,
           (DS.ItemNumber - 1) / 3 AS Grp
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@YourString,',') DS)
SELECT STRING_AGG(S.Item,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S.ItemNumber ASC) AS NewString
FROM Split S
GROUP BY S.Grp;
```

SQL Server 2016-:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = '1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345';

WITH Split AS(
    SELECT DS.Item,
           DS.ItemNumber,
           (DS.ItemNumber - 1) / 3 AS Grp
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@YourString,',') DS)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + sq.Item
              FROM Split sq
              WHERE sq.Grp = S.Grp
              ORDER BY sq.ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(8000)'),1,1,'') AS MewString

FROM Split S
GROUP BY S.Grp;
```

Comment: How to use this one in user defined table?

Comment: What do you mean "in" a User Defined Table? A View? @KalleshiKS ? A `TABLE` cannot be defined by the a statement.

Comment: Using table have to implement the above task, logic is correct but, need to use in table

Comment: YOu're not making sense, @KalleshiKS . You can't use statements like that "in" a table. A computed column's definition can only be a scalar value, it can't return multiple results. This makes no sense to be a computed Column's value as it returns multiple rows. SQL Server has no "array" data type..

Comment: Yes, I understood @Larnu. Can we do in SSRS report level

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may use an approach, based on JSON. Just transform the input text into a valid JSON array and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`:

**Example with text:**

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345'

SELECT CONCAT(
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 0 THEN [value] END),
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 1 THEN [value] END),
   MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 2 THEN [value] END)
   ) AS OutputText 
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(@json, N',', N',","'), N'"]'))
GROUP BY (CONVERT(int, [key]) / 3)
```

Result:

```
---------------
OutputText
---------------
1234,1456,3456,
7890,3457,3245,
4345
```

**Example with table:**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (TextData nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO Data (TextData)
VALUES (N'1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.TextData, c.OutputData
FROM Data d   
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT(
      MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 0 THEN [value] END),
      MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 1 THEN [value] END),
      MAX(CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [key]) % 3 = 2 THEN [value] END)
     ) AS OutputData 
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.TextData, N',', N',","'), N'"]'))
   GROUP BY (CONVERT(int, [key]) / 3)
) c
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------
TextData                            OutputData
---------------------------------------------------
1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345  1234,1456,3456,
1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345  7890,3457,3245,
1234,1456,3456,7890,3457,3245,4345  4345
```

Comment: How to use this one in user defined table for specific column

Comment: @KalleshiKS With an additional `APPLY` operator for example. See updated answer.

Comment: @KalleshiKS If this answer works, why don't you accept it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PythoMaster202. In SSRS report textbox values are keep o increasing the above values, can you help me to mplement the logic in SSRS report